# Adding a background to an SVG

Tags: xml, svg

What's a quick easy way to add a background to an SVG?  At the moment, the SVG appears to have a white background.  I am not sure if that is because the SVG file has a transparent background and is allowing the default white to come through when viewed in a browser, or if the SVG file actually have a white background.

I would like to change it so when viewed on the web, the SVG link appears to have a background.

The link consists of only the SVG file, for example, if this example link was real, it would be `http://oshiro.com/file.svg`.

Comment: What kind of background?

Comment: @RobertLongson, an image background, such as a jpg, png etc.

Comment: Create an `<image>` tag as the first item. Or fill a rect with a pattern that has an `<image>` in it.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to give you an exact answer without seeing the SVG.  But assuming you just want to add a coloured background then you can just add a `<rect>` element to the beginning of your SVG.

Try adding something like the following as the first item inside your `<svg>` element.

```
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#ffffee"/>
```